# Missing fields when submitting form

Tags: html, forms

I'm sharing this one because it's so obvious when you know it, but makes you bang your head when not!

Submitting the following form, I wasn't getting any of my fields:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" />
    <label for="lastName">Last name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" />
    <label for="address">Address: </label>
    <input type="text" id="address" />
    <label for="age">Age: </label>
    <input type="text" id="age" />
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well the answer was quite straightforward: I didn't specify a `name` attribute for my `input` fields.

Without the `name` attribute, it's impossible for the browser to send anything. So here's my working form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
    <label for="lastName">Last name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
    <label for="address">Address: </label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    <label for="age">Age: </label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" />
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```