# Not all fields are available after submit form POST

Tags: forms, post, submit

I have a simple form with a 4 fields and submit button:

- Name (text)
- Surname (text)
- Region (select)
- City (select)
- Submit (button)

For fields "Region" and "City" option-data loaded dynamically by ajax from the server.
When I fill all fields and press "Submit", I see that not all data was sent.
Only text fields were sent (Name and Surname), but select fields (which option data loaded dynamically ) - are not.
Why?

```js
function changeCities(region) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/comment/",
        context: document.body,
        data: {"region": region},
        success: function(response){
            var resp_data = JSON.parse(response);
            $.each(resp_data, function (i, item) {
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: i,
                    text: item
                }));
            });
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="surname"><br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="name"><br>
    <select id="region" onchange="changeCities(this.value)">
        <option value="default"></option>
    </select><br>
    <select id="city">%s</select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button"><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide us your code such that we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

FInally I found solution! Thanks for this question: [Missing fields when submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304445/missing-fields-when-submitting-form)

Not all fields submitted when you forgot specify "name" parameter.